# Does SPARQL works for Inferred statements also?

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege

I am using SPARQL plugin in protege to query my ontology, and I found out that it only works for asserted statements and not inferred ones. How can I change this?

Comment: Use the Snap-SPARQL plugin.

Answer (score 0):

SPARQL is defined by several standards. [SPARQL 1.1 Query](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/), the main standard, only shallowly relies on RDF semantics. A typical SPARQL query engine is not inferring anything from the RDF/RDFS terms like `rdfs:subClassOf`, `rdfs:range`, etc. However, the SPARQL standards also define [SPARQL 1.1 Entailment Regimes](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-entailment/), which defines how SPARQL engines should answer queries when they do implement inference, which is optional. In order to know whether a SPARQL query engine implements an entailment regime (such as RDFS or OWL DL), you may have to look at the documentation of the engine, or there may be a SPARQL service description available in RDF. [SPARQL 1.1 Service Description](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-service-description/) is yet another SPARQL standard that provides an RDF vocabulary, and a standard way to interpret it, for knowing what features a SPARQL engine is implementing.